# How to add multiple Flip Cards using html

Tags: html, css, flip

I am making a website in which I need to showcase the specs of a product so I am using flip cards to do so. The problem is I am trying to add multiple cards, my first one works fine, but then everything after just molds into the first one making a huge mess. I tried "googling" answers and couldn't find any that would work with me.

**My HTML Code**

```
<div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <img src="iPhone12Pro.png" alt="12pro" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h1>iPhone 12 Pro 5G</h1> 
                <p>6.1" Super Amoled Display</p> 
                <p>Good Cameras</p>
                <p>A14, 5 Nanometer Chipset</p>
                <p>Triple Camera Setup (UltraWide, Telephoto, Wide)</p>
                <p>New Sqared Off Design</p>
                <p>Price: $999 USD</p>
              </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**My CSS Code**

```
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: rgb(29, 27, 27);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-back h1 {
    padding-top: 10%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So first thing is that you just copied code from W3Schools and you copied it `WRONG`!

**First** HTML... you have 2 `<div>` more in your code then you are supposed to have.

**Second** thing is that your **CSS total mess**. Just use CSS that W3Schools gives you and everything works fine.

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="12pro" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>iPhone 12 Pro 5G</h1> 
      <p>6.1" Super Amoled Display</p> 
      <p>Good Cameras</p>
      <p>A14, 5 Nanometer Chipset</p>
      <p>Triple Camera Setup (UltraWide, Telephoto, Wide)</p>
      <p>New Sqared Off Design</p>
      <p>Price: $999 USD</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and I did as you said but now my problem is its not coming as a row and instead when I put the second card down it is indented and is in column format not row, also when I hover over one card it turns both cards and the padding element isn't working either in the css. Sorry for asking so many questions I am new to CSS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make card in row you can use flexbox... `flex-direction: row` or you can use W3Schools CSS with `w3-row` (row)

Comment: under which class should i type that because I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: @VasuBansal Don't forget... if you are using `flex-direction: row` or other flex element you also need to use `display: flex`... and these "rows" will put the cards next to each other... if you dont want that use `flex-direction: column`... And if you want to modify it, you should use rows on class `class="flip-card-inner"` (better before), because this class defines each card. If you would put more of these cards into one row they would be next to each other as I mentioned before